# C#, Object and multiple Interface implementations: how to use correctly?

Tags: c#, interface

So I have two interfaces:

```
public interface ISomething
{
    public int A();
}


public interface ISomethingElse
{
    public int B();
}
```

And an object that implements both:

```
public class MyObject : ISomething, ISomethingElse
{      
}
```

Now I have this running code:

```
...
List<MyObject> objects = myObjectManager.SelectAll(); // now have say 10 MyObject

MyUtilityClass myUtilityClass = new MyUtilityClass();
MyOtherUtilityClass myOtherUtilityClass = new MyOtherUtilityClass();
myUtilityClass.MySpecialMethod(objects);                  // <- compile failure
myOtherUtilityClass.MySpecialMethod(objects);             // <- another failure
...
```

If I want to call A or B on all of them, how can I write code like this:

```
public class MyUtilityClass
{
    public void MySpecialMethod(List<ISomething> objects) // <- the problem
    {
        foreach (ISomething o in objects)
            o.A();   
    }
}

public class MyOtherUtilityClass
{
    public void MySpecialMethod(List<ISomethingElse> objects) // <- the problem
    {
        foreach (ISomethingElse o in objects)
            o.B();   
    }
}
```

How can I cleanly call `MyUtilityClass.MySpecialMethod()` on my `List<MyObject> objects`? Is it possible without all typecasting? The parameters of `MyUtilityClass.MySpecialMethod()` appear to be the issue (I want to define the parameter as a List of objects that implement ISomething).

Comment: are you getting a compile error? What is it? 

edit: Or is the problem that you do not want to have to do the cast in MySpecialMethod?

Comment: It was indeed related to avoiding the cast.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `IEnumerable<>` interface instead of `List<>`. `IEnumerable<>` is covariant.

Comment: You can read more about covariance/contravariance [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/abhijeetp/archive/2010/01/10/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-4.0.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

List does not support **covariance**.

You may change it to `IEnumerable<ISomething>` and pass a `List<MyObject>`.

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I would use the following signature as `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant:

```
public void MySpecialMethod(this IEnumerable<ISomething> objects) // <- the problem
{
    foreach (ISomething o in objects)
        o.A();   
}
```

Calling it:

```
objects.MySpecialMethod();
```

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't

```
public void MySpecialMethod(List<MyObject> objects)
{
    foreach (ISomethingElse o in objects)
        o.B();   
}
```

work?

Comment: Yes but I want to accept any object that implements the interface not a concrete object type.